Ng Ant Icon Karma test error icon not exist or not registered
i'm new using angular with standalone components and with ssr, hydratation...
In my new project i'm using angular 18, with ng zorro 18.
but when i'm trying to use icon modules, i receive this error in KARMA test:
Error:

[@ant-design/icons-angular]:the icon dropbox-o does not exist or is not registered.
at IconNotFoundError (http://localhost:9876/karma_webpack/webpack:/node_modules/@ant-design/icons-angular/fesm2022/ant-design-icons-angular.mjs:93:12)
at call (http://localhost:9876/karma_webpack/webpack:/node_modules/@ant-design/icons-angular/fesm2022/ant-design-icons-angular.mjs:233:23);

my app.config.ts
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideClientHydration(),
    provideNzI18n(pt_BR),
    importProvidersFrom(FormsModule, NzIconModule.forChild(icons)),
    provideAnimationsAsync(),
    provideHttpClient(),
  ],
};

my app.config.server.ts
const serverConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideServerRendering(),
    importProvidersFrom(FormsModule, NzIconModule.forChild(icons)),
  ]
};

assets in angular.json:
"assets": 
  [
    {
      "glob": "**/*",
      "input": "public"
    },
    {
      "glob": "**/*",
      "input": "./node_modules/@ant-design/icons-angular/src/inline-svg/",
      "output": "/assets/"
    }
  ],

I tried exporting the module in app.config
so also change the output in angular.json to public as well
